# rolling groupby leads to double index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

When doing a groupby with rolling in pandas, the index is added twice. Bug?

```
test = DF({"a": range(10), "b": range(10)[::-1]}, index = pd.Index(np.tile([0,1], 5), name="id"))
test.sort_index(inplace = True)
test.groupby("id").rolling(window = 2).sum()

          a     b
id id            
0  0    NaN   NaN
   0    2.0  16.0
   0    6.0  12.0
   0   10.0   8.0
   0   14.0   4.0
1  1    NaN   NaN
   1    4.0  14.0
   1    8.0  10.0
   1   12.0   6.0
   1   16.0   2.0
```

Is the right fix to just set `group_keys` to `False` (it works), though I thought that was only for `apply`?